# Two drag and drop libraries having conflict

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dropzone, react-sortable-hoc

We are both using `react-sortable-hoc` and `react-dropzone` and they work fine if on separate pages. However, `react-sortable-hoc` do not work properly when `react-dropzone` is used on the same page because I noticed that `react-dropzone` also gets triggered by the drag event from the `react-sortable-hoc`. (E.g. I can no longer drag an item in between other items.)

I tried adding `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` on `react-sortable-hoc`'s `onSortStart` event but `react-dropzone` is still being triggered.

What other approach can we try to make them play nice together / not allow the other to be affected?

Comment: Why are you using two different libraries that do the same thing?

Comment: React dropzone is for dragging files, react-sortable is for sorting a list of items. They do not do the same thing.

Comment: Please show relevant code and also if possible a minimum reproducible codesandbox

Comment: Replace both of them. There are tons of similar libs, check https://github.com/bmcmahen/react-grid-dnd

Comment: @Firanolfind I found your comment not very helpful. There's often a reason why some libs are used, I suppose ;-) Then you're proposing "just another library" without evidence and without knowing the requirements. And replacing both makes no sense in that context IMHO: if you have no hint what's causing the problems, you would rather replace *one* library first. Additionally, the library you proposed doesn't handle file uploads, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a Sandbox and tried to reproduce your code which is using both `react-dropzone` and `react-sortable-hoc` at the same component. And it works well and has no problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-ganguly-khswc?file=/src/App.js:1156-1485

Comment: This helped me the most to troubleshoot. I know I should've done this myself but didn't have the time. Yeah, apparently, it's not an issue with the 2 libraries having conflict but something else.

Comment: Anyway if anyone comes across this thread, can try adding `useWindowAsScrollContainer={true}` as mine was a container issue.

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is caused when *dropping* (not when *starting the drag*): react-dropzone takes over the whole window regarding file drops, to prevent the browser from navigating away from the current page to the dropped file if the user misses the drop zone (a common annoyance).

More specifically, `dragover` and `drop` handlers are [registered on the `document`](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/blob/08a89cfd2890e9f97f96d46250d8786af7125877/src/index.js#L469):

```
document.addEventListener('dragover', onDocumentDragOver, false)
document.addEventListener('drop', onDocumentDrop, false)
```

If that's the problem you should be able to circumvent this by setting the react-dropzone [option `preventDropOnDocument`](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#src) to `false` (default is `true`).

Alternatively, you could try the react-dropzone [option `noDragEventsBubbling`](https://react-dropzone.js.org/#section-event-propagation), but I think this would handle the opposite problem (triggering events on react-sortable-hoc when dropping files)

Comment: Note: without a reproducible sandbox, we can only guess, but this answer may help the OP & I hope it will be useful for others

Comment: Apparently it wasn't a conflict issue after all. But thanks for the help.